# Given the same alias config, why is `css-loader` not resolving this image request the same way as `enhanced-resolve`?

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader

This question is contextualized using a [minimal repo](https://github.com/zyrolasting/css-loader-alias-issue) so that you can reproduce what I am seeing.

I am expecting `css-loader@0.28.0` to behave the same way as `webpack@4.12.0`'s module resolver when both the loader and Webpack use the same `alias` configuration.

Here's a selection from the repo showing the alias config and how it relates to the resolvers.

```
const context = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pkgs', target);
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const pkgsdir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pkgs');
const adir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'a');
const bdir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'b');

const alias = {
    'a': adir,
    'b': bdir,
    'packages': pkgsdir,
    '#': pkgsdir,
};

// ... snip


const wpconfig = {
    context,
    entry: path.resolve(context, 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: dist,
        filename: 'out.js',
    },
    mode: 'production',
    resolve: {
        alias,
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            alias,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                // ... snip
            },
        ],
    },
    // ... snip
};
```

Now, in that repo there is a `js` file containing `require('packages/b/img.png')`, and a `css` file in a sibling directory containing `url('packages/b/img.png')`.

Only the `js` one works. Despite what `css-loader`'s [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) say, it seems to treat the path as relative to the resolver context without noticing the alias.

Is this a bug, or did I make a configuration mistake?

Comment: Hey man, as I understood they write about @import instructions, not **url**.
For absolute urls you need to use **~** in **url**.
Example: **url("~Static/file.scss")**

But I have the some problem when I migrated from webpack 3 to 4, nothing works.

Comment: same think happened for me when I tried to added alias' to css-loader. Did you find a solution? I don't want to add relative paths to my css imports :)

Comment: In my case the error wasn't coming from css-loader, but 'react-css-modules'

Answer (score -1):

```
 {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: alias,
                  
                },
            ],
        },
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if it explained the problem and how your answer solves it.